# Metamask hangs while trying to decrypt a PDF file

Tags: metamask

I'm trying to encrypt a PDF file using the public key provided by metamask. The array buffer representing the file is converted to a Base64 string and encrypted using the eth-sig-util.
The code is given below.

```
const ethUtil = require('ethereumjs-util')
const sigUtil = require('eth-sig-util')

onFileUpload = (event) => { 

   event.preventDefault(); 

   var reader = new FileReader();

   reader.onload = async (evt) => {
     if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
       console.log("onload res ", evt.target.result);
       
         let encryptionPublicKey;
 
           await window.ethereum
           .request({
               method: 'eth_getEncryptionPublicKey',
               params: [current_account], 
           })
           .then((key) => {
               encryptionPublicKey = key;
           })
           .catch((error) => {
               if (error.code === 4001) {
               // EIP-1193 userRejectedRequest error
               console.log('We cant encrypt anything without the key.');
               } else {
               console.error(error);
               }
           }); 

           const filestr=this.arrayBufferToBase64(evt.target.result);

           const encData = sigUtil.encrypt(
             encryptionPublicKey,
             { data: filestr },
             'x25519-xsalsa20-poly1305'
           )        

           const encryptedMessage = ethUtil.bufferToHex(
             Buffer.from(
               JSON.stringify(
                 encData                    
               ),
               'utf8'
             )
           ); 
           
           window.ethereum
           .request({
             method: 'eth_decrypt',
             params: [encryptedMessage, current_account],
           })
           .then((decryptedMessage) =>
             console.log('The decrypted message is:', decryptedMessage)
           )
           .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
       }
     catch (error){
         console.error(error);
     }
     }
   };

 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.state.selectedFile);     
 };
```

[image]

When I try to decrypt it using eth_decrypt, the metamask pop up hangs. This happens only with files. It works when I encrypt and decrypt strings.strong text

Comment: I think it is a problem related to the size of the file to be decrypted. I did not find in the Metamask API documentation for `request` with `eth_decrypt` any limit in the message length to be decrypted, for this reason I think it is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/120603/91874) [pbsh](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/79294/pbsh)'s answer to my question from a few days ago.

It is not a PDF problem or Metamask bug with large files. As [pbsh](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/79294/pbsh) suggests it is not a great idea to use ECIES Asymmetric Encryption via Metamask for large files.

The solution is to generate a random key with AES symmetric encryption to encrypt the file and then encrypt the key with Metamask.