# MetaMask RPC API 'This message cannot be decrypted' using eth_decrypt

Tags: web3js, metamask, javascript, ethereumjs

I am attempting to encrypt an image, post to IPFS, get the image back from IPFS and decrypt. I have successfully achieved this with string data with no issues. When I try to do the same with image data, I can encrypt, store and retrieve from IPFS fine, but when I try to decrypt I get this error with no other information at all 'This message cannot be decrypted'. This is clearly not very helpful at all and I have no clues as to why this wouldn't work.

Encrypting/decrypting text which works perfectly fine

```
const encryptedData = ethUtil.bufferToHex(
Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(sigUtil.encrypt({
          publicKey: this.state.publicKey,
          data: JSON.stringify(this.state.credential),
          version: 'x25519-xsalsa20-poly1305',
        })), 'utf8')
);
let decryptedMessage = await window.ethereum.request({
    method: 'eth_decrypt',
    params: [encryptedMessage, this.props.account],
}).catch((error) => window.alert(error.message));
decryptedMessage = JSON.parse(decryptedMessage);
```

Trying the same thing with an image that is submitted via a form:

```
let reader = new window.FileReader();
let that = this;
reader.onloadend = function () {
let res = reader.result;
that.setState({photoString: res});
}
await reader.readAsText(photoFile);

// Encrypt photo using MetaMask
const encryptedPhoto = ethUtil.bufferToHex(
Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(sigUtil.encrypt({
  publicKey: this.state.publicKey,
  data: this.state.photoString,
  version: 'x25519-xsalsa20-poly1305',
})), 'utf8')
);
```

Comment: Perhaps it is related to his question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/120597/size-limit-decrypting-files-with-metamask.

Comment: I got the same error while accidentally using the wrong MetaMask account to decrypt the data.